# How do i correctly redirect in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework3, post-redirect-get

I have a controller with the following Code to display a list which can be searched and filtered:

```
public function listAction() {

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $post = array_filter($this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(), function($value) {
            return ($value !== null && $value !== false && $value !== ''); 
        });
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('myRoute/list', $post);
    }
    $filter = $this->params()->fromRoute();
    // Get correct Data and display as list
}
```

myRoute:

```
'myRoute' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/myRoute',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\MyController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => [
                'list' => [
                    'type' => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route'    => '/list[/page/:page][/search/:search][/type/:type]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\MyController::class,
                            'action'     => 'list',
                            'page'       => 1
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
... other routes
```

The Get-Requests are working correctly and my page loads within a few ms. But when posting data the page loads for ~5 Minutes. After that it will eventually redirect and show the correct page too.

The strange thing is, that the code is working on some machines, but on others the post -> redirect runs for ~5 minutes. The machines have the same OS and browser builds installed.

Am i using the redirect wrongly ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you added `var_dump`s to spot the part consuming so much time? Have you tried debugging using XHProf or Blackfire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `return`

so try:

```
 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myRoute/list', $post);
```

Comment: That is correct, although your code is not  - But why does this code work on some machines and on some not ?

Comment: it works on all machines. if not then the problem is somewhere else :)

Comment: You misunderstood me. The return statement was indeed missing and it is working on all machines now, im just wondering why it worked on some machines before.

Comment: hm... that would be highly impossible :) but who knows

Comment: well its working now ... still on 4/6 machines in the office its running with the faulty code and responding to every post request immediatly, on 2 its "failing" on every single post request and the ~5 minute load time appears but the page still loads after that